# bull-arena requires that the queue constructors be provided to Arena

Tags: node.js, redis, queue, typeerror

Using bull-arena: "^3.2.2" version. Facing this error on starting arena dashboard

> TypeError: as of 3.0.0, bull-arena requires that the queue constructors be provided to Arena

I tried to use the queue instance as a parameter instead of the queue name but no success.

source code:

```
import Arena from "bull-arena";
import Bull from "bull";

const queuesConfig = [];
for (const queue in queues) {
  queuesConfig.push({
    name: queues[queue],
    hostId: "worker",
    redis: { url: redisHost }
  });
}

const arenaConfig = Arena({
  queues: queuesConfig
}, {
  basePath: "/",
  disableListen: true,
});
```

Thanking you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have fixed this `type-error`. PR - [#48242](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/48242) 
They have added required constructor condition in `bull-arena` but didn't update `@types/bull-arena`. So, we were facing this issue. 
Either we have to provide Bull or Bee constructor to run the code. Now, it will work with `import` as well.

```
import Arena from "bull-arena";
import Bull from "bull";
import Bee from "bee-queue";
```

***Bull***

```
const arenaConfig = Arena({
  Bull,
  queues: queuesConfig
}, {
  basePath: "/",
  disableListen: true,
});
```

***Bee***

```
const arenaConfig = Arena({
  Bee,
  queues: queuesConfig
}, {
  basePath: "/",
  disableListen: true,
});
```

If you don't provide any queue constructor, then it will throw this error.

```
TypeError: as of 3.0.0, bull-arena requires that the queue constructors be provided to Arena
```

Comment: I had to import as 'import * as Bull from 'bull';' for this to work, but otherwise it was fine.

Comment: It's not working to bullMq

Comment: @misolo You can raise a different question for BullMQ.

Answer (score 1):

I met this problem today.

The solution is as the documentation tells you that you need to specify the library you are supporting.

It could be clearer in my eyes, but somehow it makes sense. You need to import `bull` as Bull and add it to the config.

so add

```
    const Bull = require('bull');
```

to the top of the file.

And add the imported `Bull,` to the Arena config.

```
    const arenaConfig = Arena({
        Bull,
        queues: queuesConfig
    }, {
        basePath: "/",
        disableListen: true,
    });
```

Something like this, and it should work. I implemented it in my code and it worked nicely.

```
    const Arena = require('bull-arena');

    // Mandatory import of queue library.
    const Bull = require('bull');

    const queuesConfig = [];

    for (const queue in queues) {
        console.log(queue, queues[queue]);
        queuesConfig.push({
            name: queues[queue],
            hostId: "worker",
            redis: { url: redisHost }
        });
    }

     const arenaConfig = Arena({
         // All queue libraries used must be explicitly imported and included.
         Bull,
         queues: queuesConfig
     }, {
         basePath: "/",
         disableListen: true,
     });
```

Comment: It is given in docs and tried this already. It worked in your case bcoz you are using `require` not `import`. It is a type-error related to @types/bull-arena library.